# Merge I-compiled-my-kernel-and-forgot-a-device questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions

We have at least three questions (I wouldn't be surprised to find more if I went actively looking) where someone compiled their kernel and forgot a driver and so couldn't boot. These are candidates for merging. Alternatively, as none has a really good answer, create a master question, write a good answer and close the others as duplicates.

- [error booting the custom compiled kernel 2.6.37 on ubuntu 10.04 : gave up waiting on root device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7631/error-booting-the-custom-compiled-kernel-2-6-37-on-ubuntu-10-04-gave-up-waiting)
- [kernel compilation error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4599/kernel-compilation-error)
- [Kernel can't find /dev/sda file during boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8405/kernel-cant-find-dev-sda-file-when-boot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not much point in making a fourth question. I merged into [Kernel can't find /dev/sda file during boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8405/kernel-cant-find-dev-sda-file-during-boot); all 6 answers make sense there. Good find